# Opacity of background-color of divider without text being faded

Tags: css, background, opacity, background-color, divider

Is there a way to have the background image of a divider to have it's opacity changed without the text being affected? The website I'm working on is [ubertechnews.com](http://ubertechnews.com) for the category backgrounds on the front page. Very annoying.

The specific code looks like this:

```
.recent-cat .entry.orange h3 {
background: #e8af00;
width: 207px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #c19100;
opacity: .6;
```

Comment: If the element is given an opacity the text inside it will be affected. You can either use an image with opacity and set it a background or you can have a sibling to h3 and position it such that it is behind the h3.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are talking about a background image or background color like in your css, but you can do rgba() if it is a css3 browser(not internet explorer 8 and below).

```
 .recent-cat .entry.orange h3 {
 background: rgba(232,175,0,0.6);
 width: 207px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #c19100;
 }
```